# Constructor overloads to accept any function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constructor-overloading

I am attempting to create a class template whose constructor(s) can take any kind of function as argument, that is, it takes a function pointer (which can be a member function pointer) and the corresponding function arguments. Additionally, there should be a `static_assert` that checks whether the function return type (taken from the function pointer) matches the class template parameter type. Thus, the code should look something like this:

```
template <class ReturnType>
struct Bar
{
    template <class RetType, class ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType>(RetType (* func)(ParamType ...), ParamType && ... args) :
        package_(std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(args) ...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<ReturnType, RetType>::value,
            "Type mismatch between class parameter type and constructor parameter type");
    }

    template <class RetType, class ObjType, class ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType>(RetType (ObjType::* func)(ParamType ...), ObjType * obj, ParamType && ... args) :
        package_(std::bind(func, obj, std::forward<ParamType>(args) ...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<ReturnType, RetType>::value,
            "Type mismatch between class parameter type and constructor parameter type");
    }

    std::packaged_task<ReturnType()> package_;
    std::function<void()> function_;
    std::future<ReturnType> future_;
};
```

The idea is that the code compiles for these situations, and allows for `Bar::function_` to be called (through the function call operator) without errors:

```
struct Foo
{
    int foo(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    int foo() {
        return 1;
    }
};

int foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}

int foo()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f = Foo();

    Bar<int> b1(&Foo::foo, &f, 1);
    Bar<int> b2(&Foo::foo, &f);
    Bar<int> b3(foo, 1);
    Bar<int> b4(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have close to zero experience with template metaprogramming, and even though I have ran over several questions here in SO, and attempted several ways of solving my problem, such as using a more generalized approach to the constructor

```
template <class RetType, class ... ParamType>
Bar<ReturnType>(RetType func, ParamType && ... args)
```

and combining it with `type_traits` to determine the return type), I have yet to find a way to make this work. What changes can I do to the constructor(s) that allow this functionality?

### Edit:

max66's answer solved my original problem, however, a new one arose, which I hadn't considered in the previous question. I also want to be able to pass variables to the constructor, like so:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f = Foo();
    int i = 1;

    Bar<int> b1(&Foo::foo, &f, i); // Error
    Bar<int> b2(&Foo::foo, &f, 1); // Ok
    Bar<int> b3(&Foo::foo, &f); // Ok
    Bar<int> b4(foo, i); // Error
    Bar<int> b5(foo, 1); // Ok
    Bar<int> b6(foo); // Ok

    return 0;
}
```

however, as it is, a compiler error shows up in the cases marked with `Error`. I am guessing this is because the parameter `func` in the constructor uses `ParamType` to determine its type (which doesn't match with the actual `ParamType`s in the case of `b1` and `b4`), but I have no idea how to solve this...

Comment: If you use C++17, you can use `std::invoke` to make your life easier. If you use C++14, some libraries implement the equivalent of `std::invoke` (e.g. Boost Hana has `hana::apply`)

Comment: Your example's are overloaded functions, so you "can't" just take their address without selecting a specific overload. Nonetheless, you could make your constructor take the first parameter and use a trait to ensure that it's a function type, then variadic forwarding references to take the rest of the argument, and finally employ the services of something like `std::invoke`

Comment: I am indeed using C++17 features, but I don't know much about std::invoke. How would I go about implementing the functionality I intend using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but... if you want that the return type of the funtion is equal to the template parameter of the class... why don't you simply impose it?

I mean... you can use `ReturnType` instead of `RetType`, as follows

```
template <typename ReturnType>
struct Bar
{
    template <typename ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType> (ReturnType (*func)(ParamType ...), ParamType && ... args)
      : package_(std::bind(func, std::forward<ParamType>(args) ...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
     { }

    template <typename ObjType, typename ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType> (ReturnType (ObjType::* func)(ParamType ...),
                     ObjType * obj, ParamType && ... args)
      : package_(std::bind(func, obj, std::forward<ParamType>(args) ...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
     { }
```

**-- EDIT --**

To solve the second problem, **IF** your not interested in moving parameters, you can throw away `std::forward` and `&&`, and simply write

```
template <typename ReturnType>
struct Bar
{
    template <typename ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType> (ReturnType (*func)(ParamType ...), 
                     ParamType const & ... args)
      : package_(std::bind(func, args...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
     { }

    template <typename ObjType, typename ... ParamType>
    Bar<ReturnType> (ReturnType (ObjType::* func)(ParamType ...),
                     ObjType * obj, ParamType const & ... args)
      : package_(std::bind(func, obj, args...)),
        function_([this] { package_(); }),
        future_(package_.get_future())
     { }
```

Comment: _Sigh_, of course, this indeed pretty much solves my problem and allows for the functionality I was looking for, I was so caught up in the previous implementation I had (the one with the more generalized constructor that I refer to in my question), that I forgot I no longer needed the RetType parameter, +1, and thanks

Comment: Could you please see the edit I made to the question?

Comment: @ShinuziKyura - the (new) problem is that calling `b4(foo, i);`, the second parameter type is deduced as `int &` (reference to `int`) where `foo()` receive a `int` (not reference); so the error. Same problem with `b1()`. I'm not good with refefences so I don't know how to solve this problem in a general way but... what do you want obtain, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that both `b1` and `b4` also compile, the same way one would be able to call a function that takes a `int` by giving it a variable `int i;` (which, like you said, would be a reference to `int`). Similarly, it should be impossible _i.e._ to give it a const reference when the function receives a reference. It isn't critical this works, your answer already solved the greater issue and I can live with it, but if there's a way to achieve what I just described, I would love to know.

Comment: @ShinuziKyura - but I see that you using `&&` and `std::forward`; are you interested that the parameter received can be moved? Or you can accept that the function receiving only (by example) const references?

Comment: @ShinuziKyura - answer improved in the case you're not interested in moving parameters.

Comment: Indeed, I want to accomodate for any case possible (that is, pass by value, lvalue reference, const lvalue reference, or rvalue reference)

Comment: @ShinuziKyura - Uhmm... I suppose that this deserve a completely new question. And I'm interested in answers you can receive.

Comment: I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358973/constructor-overloads-to-receive-any-type-of-reference), as for this one, I will probably mark your answer as accepted. Once again, thanks for everything.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). It handles working with member function pointers and regular functions for you.

As an outline of the sort of stuff you can do:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename F>
class Bar
{
    F f_;

public:
    template<typename TF>
    Bar(TF && f)
        : f_{ std::forward<TF>(f) }
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args &&... args) {
        return std::invoke(f_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<typename F>
auto make_bar(F && f)
{
    return Bar<std::decay_t<F>>{ std::forward<F>(f) };
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
auto b1 = make_bar(&f);
auto result = b1(myArg1, myArg2); // etc

auto b2 = make_bar(&Foo::fn);
auto result = b1(foo, arg1);
```

In the very least, I would recommend having `Bar` take the function object type as a template parameter so that you don't have to use `std::function`, but if you do want to use the exact calling syntax you have, it can be done using `std::invoke` and `std::invoke_result` as well.

Comment: max66 answer solved my problem (which turned out to be pretty trivial), but this is great info, and I will study it and potentially use it, thanks. +1